# Row number function in Mysql, facing issue with Order by clause

Tags: mysql, row-number

Data:

```
 Id | Salary |
---------------
| 1  | 100    |
| 2  | 200    |
| 3  | 300    |
```

I am trying to get Nth highest salary using the below code. 
For instance if I pass the "N" value as 1, the below code gives me 100 whereas it should be 300. I am not sure why the "order by desc" is not working properly.

```
CREATE FUNCTION gethighestsalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
DECLARE rank INT;
SET @rank = 0;
RETURN (
select a.salary FROM (select salary, @rank:=@rank+1 as chk from Employee group by salary order by salary desc) AS a
where a.chk= N
);
END
```

Comment: i don't understand why you should use `group by salary` there?

Comment: I have just provided a sample data. There could be a case when the salary is same for 2 id's.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `group by`

```
select a.salary, a.chk
FROM 
(  
    select salary, @rank := @rank + 1 as chk 
    from t 
    cross join (select @rank := 0) r
    order by salary desc
) AS a
where a.chk = 1
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe134/8)

otherwise the `order by` will not work since it orders after the grouping and then your row number is wrong.

Or keep the grouping and put it in another subquery and rank afterwards.

Comment: In case we have same salary for 2 id's the code is giving problem.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will be helpful to you,

```
SELECT Salary FROM Employee Emp1 
WHERE (N-1) = ( 
                SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Emp2.Salary)) 
                FROM  Employee Emp2
                WHERE Emp2.Salary > Emp1.Salary
              )
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64d351/3)